# Remove all xml parents, keep ones with specific children (regular expression)

Tags: regex, xml, notepad++

I'd love to delete every parent that doesn't contain specific value, such as for example

```
<drawableDictionary>l_njdocklod12</drawableDictionary>
```

Example of XML to work with below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CMapTypes name="lodetnjdock_wh1">
 <extensions />
 <archetypes>
  <Item type="CBaseArchetypeDef">
   <lodDist value="550" />
   <flags value="0" />
   <specialAttribute value="0" />
   <bbMin x="-12.3383" y="-6.42445" z="-13.3852" />
   <bbMax x="12.3382" y="6.42445" z="13.3852" />
   <bsCentre x="-5.05447E-05" y="2.38419E-06" z="0" />
   <bsRadius value="19.3046" />
   <hdTextureDist value="0" />
   <name>hash_349C91C8</name>
   <textureDictionary>njdocklod04</textureDictionary>
   <clipDictionary />
   <drawableDictionary>lodnjdocksuper11_grp</drawableDictionary>
   <physicsDictionary>nj_docks</physicsDictionary>
   <assetType>ASSET_TYPE_DRAWABLEDICTIONARY</assetType>
   <assetName>hash_349C91C8</assetName>
   <extensions />
  </Item>
  <Item type="CBaseArchetypeDef">
   <lodDist value="550" />
   <flags value="0" />
   <specialAttribute value="0" />
   <bbMin x="-5.6393" y="-5.45088" z="-4.9861" />
   <bbMax x="5.6393" y="5.45088" z="4.9861" />
   <bsCentre x="0" y="-4.76837E-07" z="4.76837E-07" />
   <bsRadius value="9.29382" />
   <hdTextureDist value="0" />
   <name>hash_46EE366B</name>
   <textureDictionary>njdocklod12</textureDictionary>
   <clipDictionary />
   <drawableDictionary>l_njdocklod12</drawableDictionary>
   <physicsDictionary>nj_docks</physicsDictionary>
   <assetType>ASSET_TYPE_DRAWABLEDICTIONARY</assetType>
   <assetName>hash_46EE366B</assetName>
   <extensions />
  </Item>
  <Item type="CBaseArchetypeDef">
   <lodDist value="550" />
   <flags value="0" />
   <specialAttribute value="0" />
   <bbMin x="-11.8993" y="-34.8797" z="-4.27972" />
   <bbMax x="11.8992" y="34.8796" z="4.29434" />
   <bsCentre x="-2.76566E-05" y="-1.52588E-05" z="0.0073123" />
   <bsRadius value="37.102" />
   <hdTextureDist value="0" />
   <name>hash_52EAB9C8</name>
   <textureDictionary>njdocklod10</textureDictionary>
   <clipDictionary />
   <drawableDictionary>lodnjdocksuper05_grp</drawableDictionary>
   <physicsDictionary>nj_docks</physicsDictionary>
   <assetType>ASSET_TYPE_DRAWABLEDICTIONARY</assetType>
   <assetName>hash_52EAB9C8</assetName>
   <extensions />
  </Item>
 </archetypes>
 <name>nj_docks_lod</name>
 <dependencies />
 <compositeEntityTypes itemType="CCompositeEntityType" />
</CMapTypes>
```

Desired result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CMapTypes name="lodetnjdock_wh1">
 <extensions />
 <archetypes>
  <Item type="CBaseArchetypeDef">
   <lodDist value="550" />
   <flags value="0" />
   <specialAttribute value="0" />
   <bbMin x="-5.6393" y="-5.45088" z="-4.9861" />
   <bbMax x="5.6393" y="5.45088" z="4.9861" />
   <bsCentre x="0" y="-4.76837E-07" z="4.76837E-07" />
   <bsRadius value="9.29382" />
   <hdTextureDist value="0" />
   <name>hash_46EE366B</name>
   <textureDictionary>njdocklod12</textureDictionary>
   <clipDictionary />
   <drawableDictionary>l_njdocklod12</drawableDictionary>
   <physicsDictionary>nj_docks</physicsDictionary>
   <assetType>ASSET_TYPE_DRAWABLEDICTIONARY</assetType>
   <assetName>hash_46EE366B</assetName>
   <extensions />
  </Item>
 </archetypes>
 <name>nj_docks_lod</name>
 <dependencies />
 <compositeEntityTypes itemType="CCompositeEntityType" />
</CMapTypes>
```

I want to archeive this using **regular expression**, using Notepad++, as I'm very far away from my comfort zone here and this worked for me so far.

Comment: Notepad++ is not the right tool when modifying XML. Use a parser that should exist in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: But it does modify xml in many cases, which is exactly what I need now. If I had favorite scripting language, I wouldn't be asking for help here.

Answer (score 3):

The tool for this job is XSLT. It's a very simple transformation: an identity template that copies everything unchanged plus a rule to delete the unwanted items:

```
<xsl:template match="Item[not(drawableDictionary='l_njdocklod12')]"/>
```

In XSLT 3.0 you get the identity template by writing

```
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
```

In older versions, write

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search for all `<Item>` elements that do not contain the value
`l_njdocklod12` using this regex:
  `<Item((?!l_njdocklod12).)*?</Item>$`

Note that `(?!` is a look-ahead, to verify that your string is not there.
I used `*?` for non-greedy match.

Ensure that `. matches newline` is checked.

To delete the found matches, replace them with the empty string.

[image]

Comment: This answer might work for this example, but in general it is totally wrong, and any attempt to solve the problem using regular expressions will be wrong. For example it might fail if the XML contains comments, or if it contains whitespace in unanticipated places, or if it contains an element whose text value  is "l_njdocklod12". Only use this kind of code if you're happy writing code that only works 99% of the time. Using regular expressions to manipulate XML is really bad practice.